# Managing an Android database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I'm looking to implement my first Android database, but I have so many questions which (I believe) are unanswered by all the tutorials I find.

Here are my needs:
- I want my application to have a database that is persistent.  If my application closes and launches again, there is already a database to pull data from.  It does not create a new database every time the application is killed and re-launched.
- I want to implement versioning.  Say version 1 of my application has a few tables.  I release version 2 and I want some sort of script to run to add new tables I've added or modify old tables I've added; and so on and so forth.  The application has to know whether the database is at a particular version (which means I'll need a table in the database) so it knows whether to run this script.

Could someone provide me with some resources so I can figure out how to do what I need? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for sqlite+android+tutorial:

http://www.hdelossantos.com/2009/12/23/creating-a-sqlite-database-in-android/

http://www.hdelossantos.com/2010/01/07/using-a-sqlite-database-in-android/

and some more:

http://www.google.com.hk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android+sqlite+tutorial

There is also a sample in the sample programs that come with the SDK, i.e. the Notepad app.

And the official developer api doc - but that's more as a reference, not as tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html